# How to make an arbitrary Microsoft FILETIME?

Tags: windows-7, date-time, algorithm

I would like to make an arbitrary Microsoft FILETIME. The algorithm
is more important than the Microsoft programming language.

For example if today is June 2 2016, I would like to calculate the 
FILETIME at midnight June 2016.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT June 2 2016 5:09 P.M Here is the program which is causing me
headaches:

Microsoft SYSTEMTIME in nanoseconds is 1467432000.
  Microsoft FILETIME in nanoseconds for the same date-time stamp is 1470186549.

Here is my algorithm. May I ask what I did wrong?]

```
void _wapi_time_t_to_filetime(time_t timeval, FILETIME* filetime)
{
    int64_t ticks;

    ticks = ((int64_t)timeval * 10000000) + 116444736000000000ULL;
    filetime->dwLowDateTime = ticks & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    filetime->dwHighDateTime = ticks >> 32;
}


int64_t FileTime_to_POSIX(FILETIME ft)
{
    FILETIME localFileTime;
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &localFileTime);
    SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&localFileTime, &sysTime);
    struct tm tmtime = { 0 };
    tmtime.tm_year = sysTime.wYear - 1900;
    tmtime.tm_mon = sysTime.wMonth; // -1;
    tmtime.tm_mday = sysTime.wDay;
    tmtime.tm_hour = sysTime.wHour;
    tmtime.tm_min = sysTime.wMinute;
    tmtime.tm_sec = sysTime.wSecond;
    tmtime.tm_wday = 0;
    tmtime.tm_yday = 0;
    tmtime.tm_isdst = -1;
    time_t ret = mktime(&tmtime);
    return ret;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SYSTEMTIME stUTCStart, stUTCFinish;
    FILETIME  ftStart, ftFinish;

    int64_t elapsedNanoSeconds(0);

    GetSystemTime(&stUTCStart);
    printf("%d nanoseconds\n", ConvertSYSTEMTIMEToNanoseconds(stUTCStart));

    struct tm tmtime = { 0 };
    tmtime.tm_year = 2016 - 1900;
    tmtime.tm_mon = 6; 
    tmtime.tm_mday = 2; 
    tmtime.tm_hour = stUTCStart.wHour;
    tmtime.tm_min = stUTCStart.wSecond;
    tmtime.tm_sec = stUTCStart.wSecond;
    tmtime.tm_wday = stUTCStart.wDayOfWeek;
    tmtime.tm_yday = 132;
    tmtime.tm_isdst = -1;
    time_t ret = mktime(&tmtime);
    _wapi_time_t_to_filetime(ret, &ftStart);

    printf("%d nanoseconds\n", FileTime_to_POSIX(ftStart));
    return 0;


  }
```

Comment: Programming question are off-topic. You should know where to post it as you have an account on [so]. Are you question banned over there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I found in the mono source code.

```
void _wapi_time_t_to_filetime (time_t timeval, WapiFileTime *filetime)
{
    guint64 ticks;

    ticks = ((guint64)timeval * 10000000) + 116444736000000000ULL;
    filetime->dwLowDateTime = ticks & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    filetime->dwHighDateTime = ticks >> 32;
}
```

Comment: The way I am applying this algorithm is incorrect. May I ask how to fix its application? Thank you.

Comment: Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

there are at least 3 different filetimes for windows filesystem.

the easiest way to do it is powershell, this is the preferred way when dealing with Windows on OS level and should be the right way for a question in the superuser area of the stack exchange network.

```
$time = get-date -hour 0 -Minute 0   # this is today midnight
$file = "c:\yourfile.txt"
$file.CreationTime = $time
```

and if you like:

```
$file.LastAccessTime = $time
$file.LastWriteTime = $time
```